# get the values in a given radius from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask, spatial-query

I want to recover a "buffer" around a given value in a 2-D numpy array in python. The idea is to select all the values comprised within a given radius and then mask them. It would be something like:

1. select a "cell" in the matrix, like `matrix[x, y]`
2. get the cells comprised in the neighborhood, where the distance from `x, y` is less than the radius `r`

I would like to implement a fast function for doing so, since I have a big array for processing (shape is 7000 x 10000).

Comment: Can you define "distance"?

Comment: All the values comprised in [x-n:x+1+n, y-n:y+1+n < = r*r]

Answer (score 3):

numpy slicing does this for you out of the box, and it is very fast:

```
x
Out[38]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])

x[0:3,0:3] #neighbors distance=1 from (1,1)
Out[39]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

If you want to generalize this, write a wrapper:

```
def n_closest(x,n,d=1):
    return x[n[0]-d:n[0]+d+1,n[1]-d:n[1]+d+1]
```

demo:

```
y = np.diag(np.ones(10))

n_closest(y,(1,3))
Out[67]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])

n_closest(y,(2,3),d=2)
Out[69]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

This is a basic 'square' mask, if you need a different shaped one it is easy to make one.  It's unclear if that's what you wanted.

Comment: This is correct only if you assume he meant the distance to be the L-infinity norm.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I'm trying to figure out how to make a disc shape.

Comment: @Guadancil11 then yes you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647024/how-to-apply-a-disc-shaped-mask-to-a-numpy-array.  The same strategy applies, you are just slicing using `np.ogrid`.

Comment: I guess I'm missing the point. I make:                                  >>> ax,ay=ogrid[x-d:x+d+1,y-d:y+d+1]
>>> mask = ax*ax + ay*ay <= d*d    And the mask is all 'False'

Comment: Actually it is quite different... In your answer you are creating a view of the original data. In the other case, you are creating a boolean mask that can be used to access a flattened copy of the original data.

Comment: I see the error, @Jaime. It was a newbie error. Now it works great, thank you all.