# numpy and detecting .mean() in a radius

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm pretty new to numpy. 
I have been looking around how to do this but I can't find anything easy enough.

This is the problem.
I'm identifying particles in red (it's ok and done) so I have an array with locations.

I make a new image with these locations with grey dilation and scipy.ndimage, having the dilated positions with a value and the rest 0.

Then I multiply this image with another image (green color), so that the new color only has signals where you have particles in red. What I want to do is to detect the mean of intensities in this other color per given point, in a given radius or square for example.

How can I do this? Do I make scipy.ndimage.measurements.label in the initial color and then use the same array indexes to have the means? Or I can just have x,y coordinates and do the mean() over a given radius?

Comment: Are you essentially wanting to perform a 2D moving average over your image?

Comment: If I understand correctly a 2D moving average is to smooth the image (or do convolutions). If that's the case, no.     What I want to know are the values around multiple given x,y 's (giving a radius or the area of a square) and obtain a mean value of these positions. Is there an easy callable function for this?

Comment: Ok, I would tone it down a little bit. You have a 2D array (the red image) where only some of the positions are different from zero. You multiply it by another 2D array, so the result is a 2D array where only the points different from zero in the first one is itself different from zero. Now, where do you want to meassure those averages you are talking about?

Comment: Exactly Jblasco. That's what I am doing. But now I want to measure the averages of each point around a  given x and y. For example a = np.ones((10,10)) ; a[5,5] = 1 I want to know all the values around 5,5 with a given radius (structuring element of size (2,2 or 3,3)?) and calculate the mean. This, in the output array from the multiplication

Comment: So you want to specify coordinates around which to collect the mean?

Comment: This question should help you out.  You can create a "circular" mask using `ogrid`, then use it to select the data you want to take the average of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647024/how-to-apply-a-disc-shaped-mask-to-a-numpy-array

Comment: Yes that's want I want, thanks. So basically I have to do a new mask for every coordinate and measure the mean. I guess that's easy!! thanks a bunch. I guess I could use slicing around x and y as well if I want a square mask.

Comment: http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/#measuring-objects-properties-ndimage-measurements <- good tutorial