# Transform sensor intensity values to pixel intensity in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a vector A of size 88 A= [n1,n2,...,n88] Each value of the vector has a sensor voltage intensity reading that range from 0 to 1. I want to transform those intensity values to pixel intensity values as in the following image:
[image]
The image has 280 x 420 pixeles where the 88 sensors are evenly distributed. White color represents a reading of 0 and black color represents a reading of 1. 
Can someone please tell me how can I implement this in Python using matplotlib?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you need these ellipse forms?

Comment: I think the idea would be to initialize an array the size of your image (`zeros((420, 280))`), and then add disks multiplied by your data value wherever you want them. See this question: [How to apply a disc shaped mask to a numpy array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647024/how-to-apply-a-disc-shaped-mask-to-a-numpy-array)

Comment: @MaxNoe Yes, I need my experiment to be as similar as this one.

Comment: @castle-bravo  Thank you for the suggestion, I think I get your idea but how can i plot the disks?

Comment: I 'll add a solution tomorrow

Comment: Are the sensors actually elliptical? (just curious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pylab import figure, show, rand, colorbar
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib import cm

#dummy data
A = rand(88)

#todo: are the i and j loops in the right order for the data?
spots = [Ellipse(xy=(i*475/11. + 18,j*275/8. + 16 + 16*(i%2 > 0)),
                 width=20, height=25)
        for i in range(11) for j in range(8)]

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

p = PatchCollection(spots, cmap=cm.cubehelix_r)
p.set_array(A)
p.set_edgecolor('face')
ax.add_collection(p)
colorbar(p)

ax.set_xlim(0, 420)
ax.set_ylim(280, 0)

show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Cphlewis, Thank you for your answer! the results is perfect. You just showed me many functions from matplotlib that I did not know about. the sensor arrangement and shape (as you asked) is as in the following image: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hu5kdopakhxxxyw/sensorarrangement.PNG?dl=0)  Do you know where I can find the availible colors (as cubehelix_r) for the color bar? Since I want it to be as similar as possible. Thank you again!

Comment: You can define your own colormap (http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) : cubehelix_r was just the closest one from the standard set.

Comment: Hi Cphlewis, as you can see in the image the sensor allocation goes from bottom to top and left to right. also the first eight sensor columns have 7 sensors, then the ninth column has 6 sensors, the tenth 7 sensors, the eleventh 6 sensors, the twelve 7 sensors and the thirteenth 6 sensors for a total of 88 sensors. can you please help me modify your program to reflect this change? Thank you.

Comment: @user3025898 Everything you need to change should be in this line:
`spots = [Ellipse(xy=(i*475/11. + 18,j*275/8. + 16 + 16*(i%2 > 0)),
                 width=20, height=25)
        for i in range(11) for j in range(8)]`

Comment: I'll leave modifying the xy-definitions to you, since (a) you can do it by experimenting with the code (b) it's so specific to your sensor layout (c) it's basically algebra and _hint_ (d) you could just type in a list `[(x1,y1), (x2, y2) ...]` of sensor centers and use that as your for-loop.

Comment: Ok that is all I need, again thanks for your help :)