# Local Maxima with circular window

Tags: python, numpy, filtering

I am trying to compute a local maxima filter on a matrix, using a circular kernel.
The output should be the cells that are local maximas. For each pixel in the input 'data', I need to see if it is a local maximum by a circular window, thus returning a value of 1, otherwise 0.

I have this code, built upon answers from here:
[How to apply a disc shaped mask to a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647024/how-to-apply-a-disc-shaped-mask-to-a-numpy-array)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as sc

radius = 2
kernel = np.zeros((2*radius+1, 2*radius+1))
y,x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1, -radius:radius+1]
mask2 = x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2
kernel[mask2] = 1

def local_maxima(matrix, window_size):
    loc_max = sc.maximum_filter(matrix, window_size, mode='constant')
    return loc_max


data = np.array([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)])

loc_max = sc.filters.generic_filter(data, local_maxima(data, np.shape(kernel)), footprint=kernel)
max_matrix = np.where(loc_max == data, 1, 0)
np.savetxt('.....\Local\Test_Local_Max.txt', max_matrix, delimiter='\t')
```

The kernel has this shape:

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]]
```

So the search cells will be only the ones that have value 1. The cells with 0 should be excluded from the local maxima search.

But the script gives the error below on line 21:

> ```
> RuntimeError: function parameter is not callable
> ```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The problem is that the function you give to `sc.filters.generic_filter` is applied to each element of the input array you give: `data`, which is not possible as the function local_maxima takes an array as argument and not a float or integer... I don't know exactly the goal of your code but why don't you just apply that: `loc_max = sc.maximum_filter(data, kernel.shape, mode='constant', footprint=kernel)`

Comment: Because the footprint kernel should only take the positions that are 1 in the kernel matrix, not the ones with 0 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the code below that return `1` if the cell visited is a local maximum by a circular window defined by `kernel` (I just used `%pylab` to plot the results as an illustration):

```
%pylab
import scipy.ndimage as sc
data = np.array([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)])
matshow(data)
colorbar()
```

[image: data]

```
radius = 2
kernel = np.zeros((2*radius+1, 2*radius+1))
y,x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1, -radius:radius+1]
mask2 = x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2
kernel[mask2] = 1
matshow(kernel)
colorbar()
```

[image: kernel]

```
def filter_func(a):
    return a[len(a)/2] == a.max()
out = sc.generic_filter(data, filter_func, footprint=kernel)
matshow(out)
colorbar()
```

[image: output]

Below is the result with a random input data array:

```
data = np.random.random(size=data.shape)
matshow(data)
```

[image: random array]

```
out = sc.generic_filter(data, filter_func, footprint=kernel)
matshow(out)
colorbar()
```

[image: output on random array]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is what I needed. Nice plots! :)

Comment: I' don't know which answer to accept. pseudoDust's answer was first, but yours is more easy to follow...

Comment: Always select the better answers (and not the ones who were first), so that people who later look this up see the better answer first. In this case I agree that @bougui 's answer is better :)

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of `sc.filters.generic_filter()` should be a function, you are passing it the value returned by the `local_maxima(data, np.shape(kernel))` call, i.e. a matrix.

I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you have done here, but I think you do not need the `generic_filter` call at all, `maximum_filter` should do what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as sc

radius = 2
kernel = np.zeros((2*radius+1, 2*radius+1))
y,x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1, -radius:radius+1]
mask2 = x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2
kernel[mask2] = 1

data = np.array([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),  
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),  
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1),  
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),  
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),  
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)])

loc_max = sc.maximum_filter(data, footprint=kernel, mode='constant')
max_matrix = np.where(loc_max == data, 1, 0)
np.savetxt('.....\Local\Test_Local_Max.txt', max_matrix, delimiter='\t')
```

(I do not have python installed on this computer so I have not tested this out, sorry)

Edit:
I've tested it and it seems to give the correct result:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: It runs, but it's not the result I expect. For each pixel in the input 'data', I need to see if it is a local maximum by a circular window, thus returning a value of 1, otherwise 0. The output from your answer is doesn't add 0 when the cell is not a local maxima.

Comment: I've now tested it, seems to be doing what you want, I'll add the result I'm getting to the answer